# How can I add click Event to image on Html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a web site and it is about travel. There too many photos in the home. and I have to make them clickable.How images could be able to click? Heeeelp!!

Comment: How do we know what your application is like without you showing us your code? If you want help, please write down your code first.

Comment: Don't get discouraged by negative votes pal, I got lots of them when I started coding, don't get it personal, this community is not very welcoming at first ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the best way is adding an ID to your image like

```
<img id="image" src="..." alt="...">
```

and then put a script tag somewhere in your HTML file

```
<script>

document.getElementById("image").onclick = function() {

// code goes here

}

</script>
```

Although this way your code will be pretty messy, so you can put your JS code into an external file and call the function from there